# Run a program from a downloaded zip file

Tags: software-installation

I am trying to run a program as it is saying to do on the website but it doesn't work. I am really new on Ubuntu and I would appreciate any help please.
On the website is saying :

To run it: unzip the file, CD to the sedlog-3.1 directory and type `java -jar SedLog.jar`.

`sedlog-3.1` is the name of the program I am trying to run. When I type java -jar SedLog.jar on the sedlog-3.1 directory, I get this message back :

```
kate@Riley:~/sedlog-3.1$ java -jar SedLog.jar
The program 'java' can be found in the following packages:
 * default-jre
 * gcj-5-jre-headless
 * openjdk-8-jre-headless
 * gcj-4.8-jre-headless
 * gcj-4.9-jre-headless
 * openjdk-9-jre-headless
Try: sudo apt install <selected package>
```

I really don't know what stupid mistake I do and I can't short that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have Java Run-time (JRE) installed which is required to run .jar files.

To install JRE, run

```
sudo apt install default-jre openjdk-8-jre
```